# How to make a transparent UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have an app with a `UITableView` and a corresponding detail view for each row. In the detail view I have to display some text and a background image (text is different for each row, but the image remains the same). The easiest way, in my opinion, is to put the text in an .rtf file and display it in a `UIWebView`. Then just put a `UIImageView` behind the `UIWebView`.

I've tried to set the `UIWebView`'s opacity to zero in IB, but it didn't help.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 304, accepted):

I recommend:

```
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

(setting these properties in Interface Builder will work for iOS 5.0+, but for iOS 4.3 you must set the backgroundColor *in code*)

And include this into your HTML code:

```
<body style="background-color: transparent;">
```

Comment: Works iOS 5. At least in the simulator.

Comment: I was able to set opacity and backgroundColor in IB. For me the style tag was what was keeping this from working.

Comment: this way works for 4.2.1 if you write these strings as code only. If you setup the same options in iterface builder than you will not get a transparent background

Comment: The `<body style="background-color: transparent;">` seems to be optional, at least in recent iOS versions.

Answer (score 21):

Use the recursive method below to remove gradient from UIWebView:

```
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self hideGradientBackground:webView];


- (void) hideGradientBackground:(UIView*)theView
{
  for (UIView * subview in theView.subviews)
  {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
      subview.hidden = YES;

    [self hideGradientBackground:subview];
  }
}
```

Comment: don't forgot to write webView.opaque = NO;

Comment: Uh, what "gradient" are we talking about here?

Answer (score 8):

Swift update:

```
webView.opaque = true
webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

And again, don't forget to set

```
<body style="background-color: transparent">
```

Or better still, instead of an inline style, in your style sheet:

```
body {
     background-color: transparent
}
```

Comment: I didn't need to set body style. But I had to set background color and opaque in code.

Answer (score 6):

**For Swift 3 and Xcode 8**

```
self.webView.isOpaque = false;
self.webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score 4):

In XCode 6.x uncheck **Opaque** and change **Background's opacity** to **0%**. I think other XCode versions will also work.[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make my UIWebView transparent by going to 'Attributes Inspector' and unchecking Drawing Opaque.

My HTML code just for reference.

```
    UIWebView* webView =(UIWebView *) [cell viewWithTag:100];
    NSString* htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"<html>"
                                   "<style type='text/css'>html,body {margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%%;height: 100%%;}</style>"
                                   "<body>"
                                   "<table style='border:1px solid gray; border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden;color:white;font-size:10pt' cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"1\" align='right'><tr>"
                                   "<td>Hello</td><td>There</td>"
                                   "</tr></table>"
                                   "</body></html>"
                                   ];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4.x,

```
webView.backgroundColor = .clear
openSourceLicensesWebView.isOpaque = false
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the scrolls and make the `UIWebView` transparent, try this code below:

```
webView.opaque = NO;  
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  

for(UIView *view in webView.subviews){   
     if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {  
          // to transparent   
          [view removeFromSuperview];  
     }  
     if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {  
          UIScrollView *sView = (UIScrollView *)view;  
          //to hide Scroller bar 
          sView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;  
          sView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
          for (UIView* shadowView in [sView subviews]){  
               //to remove shadow  
               if ([shadowView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {  
                    [shadowView setHidden:TRUE];  
               }  
          }  
     }   
}
```