# iOS rendering HTML tags with hyperlinks and images

Tags: html, ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to render a post in HTML tags that contain images and hyperlinks but I could not get them to work ideally in a `UITableViewCell` and I have searched around Google and have tried two existing solutions;

The first one is to use a `UIWebView` to display the HTML tags which I have tried but it doesn't resize itself according to the size of the content and seems to have a fixed size. (This means I don't want horizontal and vertical scrolling, it should have the same behavior as `UILabel` except it contains images and hyperlinks). It doesn't have the native behavior and is taking up alot of memory.

The second one I tried was to use a `UITextView` to render the HTML tags using `NSAttributedStrings` and `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` but all the links in the HTML disappear and it makes things difficult.

Example [HTML text](http://pastebin.com/5k4asx5a)

Comment: All the link "disappear"? How is that? Do you have an example of html text not working and your code to render it?

Comment: They disappear as in they don't show up after it has been parsed by `NSHTMLTextDocumentType`. I added an example HTML text document that I was using earlier. The codebase for parsing the HTML is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879837/how-to-display-html-formatted-text-in-ios-label

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIWebView and resize the height of the webview according to the size of your content.
1. Set the webView delegate
2. Set the html inside a div with id "container" to be measured

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self
    webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><div id='container'>Put your content inside this div to ve measured</div></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    var js = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById(\"container\").offsetHeight;")!
    if js == ""{ js = "0" }
    let height = CGFloat(js)
    // now resize your height with this value, modify the frame or the constrains according to your design
}
```