# load html string in ios swift except UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I want to load the following html string in Uitableview cell.How to load it ?

```
<p>\r\n\t  Whether you are viewing a premium-quality 2D picture or seeing incredible 3D depth, images are breathtakingly real in Samsung Full HD. Combine with a 3D TV and 3D active shutter glasses to view the latest Hollywood 3D titles or amplify your viewing experience by upconverting 2D content to immersive 3D.\r\n</p>
```

Comment: is this string for UILabel?

Comment: yes .String to be loaded to Label

Comment: checkout RTLabel [link](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel)

Comment: try this, same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879837/how-to-display-html-formatted-text-in-ios-label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `NSAttributed String` for load in UILabel or use `UItextView` to load HTML String for e.g

```
let htmlString: String = "<p>\r\n\t  Whether you are viewing a premium-quality 2D picture or seeing incredible 3D depth, images are breathtakingly real in Samsung Full HD. Combine with a 3D TV and 3D active shutter glasses to view the latest Hollywood 3D titles or amplify your viewing experience by upconverting 2D content to immersive 3D.\r\n</p>"

let  attrStr: NSAttributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding), options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)


yourlabel.attributedText = attrStr
```

for additional help see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414999/html-format-in-uitextview)

else if you need third party lib use [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel) it will load the all type of string in label

Comment: am getting the error Type 'String' has no member '.DocumentAttribute'

Answer (score -1):

Then you have to take web view in your table view cell because without `webview` how you can load the `html string`. According to my knowledge it is not possible to load `html query` except `UIWebView`.

So, you can take `UIWebView` in tableview's cell and can load html to that webview in `cellforrowatindexpath` method.