# Embedding a url in only part of a string in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Is there a way to embed a url into only part of a string in UILabel WITHOUT using TTTAttributedLabel?

For example, in the following string @"For more information [click here](http://stackoverflow.com). Thank you!"

"Click here" would be the underlined hyperlink, but the rest of the string would not be clickable. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

Or use `UIWebView`:
`[webView loadHTMLString:yourString baseURL:nil];`
 and [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to handler click link event

[More in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138336/how-to-show-html-text-from-api-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is with attributed strings you can assign characteristics like color, underline and link to a rave within the string.

Comment: This answer would be must more useful if it provided details about how to implement this feature.