# parsed webpage background is not transparent in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uiwebview

My webpage is displaying text parsed from xml.but it is showing the background as white which i want to be transparent as i have a wooden image behind webView. i have created my WebView through IB. i have set it to snow color opacity to zero.set its delegate.Even parsed webpage is also having tags for transparent, but no result.

XML is

<Information><body style="background-color: transparent">LITOFINTER es una empresa de servicios de comunicación gráfica de vanguardia.Proveemos soluciones a las necesidades de comunicación y marketing empresariales, tanto en soporte papel como en formato electrónico.Tenemos capacidad propia de producción gráfica (rotativas comerciales y máquinas planas para más de 3 millones de pliegos de 16 páginas diarios, más encuadernación y todo tipo de acabados) combinada con servicios de impresión digital (personalización y segmentación para enviar mensajes impresos diferentes para cada receptor), impresión bajo demanda (bajas tiradas, mismo o diferente contenido), y marketing online (comunicación por internet y en dispositivos móviles).Somos una empresa innovadora en la integración de diferentes soluciones complementarias (sobre soporte papel y soporte digital) para acciones de marketing multicanal. Nuestros servicios comienzan desde la asesoría y consultoría en el diseño de la solución óptima de comunicación gráfica, sobre diferentes formatos y canales. Nuestros clientes pueden beneficiarse de una oferta única de integración de servicios, tradicionalmente desconcertados, y que ahora Litofinter integra de forma innovadora.Los medios de impresión y producción propios nos permiten ofrecer precios muy competitivos controlando directamente la calidad y tiempos de entrega, a la vez que desarrollamos servicios de vanguardia sobre nuevas tecnologías. LITOFINTER ,su gestor de comunicación gráfica multicanal.</body></Information>

it is showing like this [image]

Comment: Look at this post - [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646930/how-to-make-a-transparent-uiwebview

Comment: @nanjunda :- Thanks a ton..... do one thing paste this same answer in answer as you make my morning..... it works :) i want to give points to you... :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a transparent UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646930/how-to-make-a-transparent-uiwebview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go -

Set property

```
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

HTML code:

```
<body style="background-color: transparent;">
```