# how do you set a transparent background for an iFrame in an iOS application?

Tags: ios, xcode, iframe

I have a UIWebView displaying an iFrame, I have the webview set to clear color, and the iFrame set to transparent, but for some reason I am still getting a white block instead of a clear iFrame. Is there something else I need to do ?

iFrame Code:

```
<iframe src=\"http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FmySite&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId=31301291871XXXX\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:hidden; width:125px; height:40px;\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>
```

iOS code:

```
NSString *likeButtonHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HTML><BODY>%@</BODY></HTML>", likeButtonIframe];   

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(650, 95, 125, 40)];

[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[webView loadHTMLString:likeButtonHtml baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
webView.opaque = NO;
```

You may also need this on your HTML:

```
<style>body {background-color: transparent;}</style>
```

Comment: And for a few more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646930/how-to-make-a-transparent-uiwebview

Comment: Hey - I just tested it, and the "webView.opaque = NO;" worked perfectly! Thank you.