# UIWebView background is set to Clear Color, but it is not transparent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm developing an iOS 4 application using iOS SDK latest version and XCode 4.2.

I have a XIB with a `UIWebView` with **Alpha = 1.0**, **Background** set to **Clear Color** and **Opaque** is not set. On this XIB I setup an image as background with this code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AboutBackground.png"]];
        self.view.backgroundColor = background;
        [background release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The `UIWebView` is showing an static html:

```
<html><head></head><body style=\"margin:0 auto;text-align:center;background-color: transparent; color:white\">...</body></html>
```

On iOS 5 simulator, its background is transparent, but on an iOS 4 device is grey.

Any clue?

Comment: try to just put an UIImageView on your webview in interface builder and set it your image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the web view doesn't fill the entire screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a transparent UIWebVIew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646930/how-to-make-a-transparent-uiwebview)

Answer (score 366, accepted):

Also set :

```
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[webView setOpaque:NO];
```

Comment: This only works for me if I set the background color and opaqueness after calling loadHTMLString. It seems like loadHTMLString resets both of those values.

Comment: I know the question was for iOS, but if for OSX, this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34525808/105539) resolves the problem and may also help those with iOS too.

Comment: This solution is still working in iOS 12.1, Xcode 10.1 and Swift.

Answer (score 15):

```
     /*for ios please set this*/

     [webViewFirst setOpaque:NO];

     /*for html please set this*/
     <body style="background:none">
```

Answer (score 9):

Besides setting your webview's background to clear color, also make sure that you set opaque to false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but opaque is not set on Interface Builder.

Comment: Try setting it after calling [super viewDidLoad:animated]; .

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue..works on ios5 but grey background on ios4. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code (i know, that it's unsafe, but it works even for ios5):

```
- (void)makeBodyBackgroundTransparent {
        for (UIView *subview in [webView subviews]) {
            [subview setOpaque:NO];
            [subview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }
        [webView setOpaque:NO];
        [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
webView.opaque = NO;

webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *content=@"example clear background color UIWebview";
NSString *style=[NSString stringwithformat:@"<html><head><style>body {background-color:transparent;}</style></head><body>%@</body></html>",content];
[myWebview loadhtmlstring:style baseurl:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

Latest Swift Version (as required):

```
lazy var webView: UIWebView = {
    let view = UIWebView()
    view.delegate = self
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.isOpaque = false
    return view
}()
```

*Remove delegate line if not required*

Answer (score 1):

For Objective

```
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Please make sure to include this into your HTML code:

```
<body style="background-color: transparent;">
```

or

```
 <body style="background:none">
```