# iOS : WebView Background color to transparent

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview, transparency, background-color

What I want is set the background color of webview to transparent.

Below is the code I am using for webview.

```
NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body style=\"background-color: transparent;font-family: verdana;\"><h3>About US</h3></BODY></HTML>"];
[webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

However when I use this, I still see background color as WHITE. Any idea how to get color to transparent?

Comment: Interesting that Q's with accepted 0-vote answers still appear as unanswered.

Comment: @JanDvorak : I don't get you...

Comment: I was browsing the `newest unanswered` category and saw a yellow number, so I came to see

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIWebView background is set to Clear Color, but it is not transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667150/uiwebview-background-is-set-to-clear-color-but-it-is-not-transparent)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is all it should take,

```
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[webView setOpaque:NO];
```

Comment: [webView setOpaque:NO];  is the key

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line.

```
webView.opaque=NO;
```