# UIWebView's content background color not transparent

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm using an UIWebView to load some HTML text from a plist.

I managed to make its background transparent using

```
webView.opaque = NO;
webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

but the content, which is the text loaded from the plist, is shown with a disturbing white background.

I'm loading it using

```
NSString *descr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style> body{font-size:16; font-family: Helvetica; color: black;} strong{font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size:16} .bg{background:transparent;}</style></head><body><div class='bg'>%@</div></body></html>",[item valueForKey:@"description"]];
[webView loadHTMLString:descr baseURL:nil];
```

I've tried setting the `.bg` class background color to `rgba(255,0,0,0.0)`, but nothing worked.

Also tried setting `webView.scrollView.backgroundColor : [UIColor clearColor];`

Any advice on how to get the UIWebView's content background transparent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIWebView background is set to Clear Color, but it is not transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667150/uiwebview-background-is-set-to-clear-color-but-it-is-not-transparent)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this !

```
[webView setOpaque:NO];
webView.bakgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Did you change something in the Storyboard or nib file?

Comment: No, anything. The opaque is disabled on the Storyboard as well.

Comment: No, there's no javascript or URL, it's just some text took from my plist.

Comment: did u check or uncheck Use Autolayout?

Comment: It's unchecked, I'm not using it

Comment: [webView loadHTMLString: @"<html><body style='background-color: transparent'></body></html>" baseURL: nil];
try to add <body style='background-color:transparent'>

Comment: http://banagale.com/using-an-html-web-view-with-a-transparent-background-iphone-interface-builder.htm

Answer (score 1):

In XCode 6.x uncheck **Opaque** and change **Background's opacity** to **0%**. I think other XCode versions will also work.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML body will still have a background color.

You need to add 'background-color:transparent;' to the body part of your CSS

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3935033/78496

Comment: Tried that, but there's still that kinda whitey background. I'm guessing it's a sort of "overlay" being put by default?

Comment: Sorry, it should've been 'background-color' I've updated the answer.