# How to make webview transparent?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, webview

I want to make my webview to look transparent and show the data on it with background showing images of parent view.

Can anyone please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a subclass of `UIView`, which means you can set its [`backgroundColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW30) property to a transparent [`UIColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006892-CH3-SW33):

```
myWebview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: see this post...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3935033/845115

Answer (score 4):

it may be help to u

```
[webView setOpaque:NO]; 
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code is use for solve your problem

```
    NSString *htmlData=@"your data string here";

    [self.webVctr loadHTMLString:strForhtmldata baseURL:nil];
```

now webview transparent for that following code to use.

```
    self.webVctr.opaque = NO;
    self.webVctr.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```