# how to set UIWebView background color?

Tags: ios4, uiwebview

I used in MainWindow.xib and added one image view and set image (for background).

now in my webview page i wrote this code

```
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[webView setOpaque:YES];
```

and also `[webView setOpaque:NO];`

but i am not getting  MainWindow.xib image background in webview?
any one pls help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this (and I quote from the great Ortwin Gentz):

```
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

(for some reason it didn't work to set those properties via IB) and include this into your HTML code:

```
<body style="background-color: transparent;">
```

You see the original question here, please also upvote Ortwin's answer there: [How to make a transparent UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646930/how-to-make-a-transparent-uiwebview)