# How to make UIWebview Transparent.?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a XIB with a UIWebView with Alpha = 1.0, Background set to Clear Color and Opaque is not set. On this XIB I setup an image as background with this code:

The UIWebView is showing an static html:

```
<html><head></head><body style=\"margin:0 auto;text-align:center;background-color: transparent; color:white\">...</body></html>
```

Any Solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a transparent UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646930/how-to-make-a-transparent-uiwebview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this...

```
webViewFirstTab.opaque=NO;

for (UIView* subView in [webViewFirstTab subviews])
{
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        for (UIView* shadowView in [subView subviews])
        {
            if ([shadowView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                [shadowView setHidden:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not work for me on iOS6 or iOS7. The UIWebView holds a _UIWebViewScrollView which holds a UIWebBrowserView. Setting the backGround color of all 3 views to clear color does not result in a transparent background. I also have the html like this:

Anybody got this to work on iOS 6 or 7?