# UIWebView transparent with YouTube player shows native player behind on iOS 7 (Bug?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube, ios7

I'm currently updating an app for **iOS 7** and discovered that by making a **UIWebView** transparent ([how-to-make-a-transparent-uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646930/how-to-make-a-transparent-uiwebview/11964365)) and adding a YouTube video inside, it will show the native version of that video player behind the content:

**[Screenshot of the bug](http://cl.ly/image/2v2M3Z3f0f02)**

I already tried looping all the web view subviews and asking on the Apple dev forums, but nothing yet. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- You should add new UIView with same frame size as your transparent UIWebview.
- Then add your transparent uiwebview on this new UIView instead of your main view. So your main view will be automatically hide.

I mean hiding and showing new view. Your new view will come up with your transparent webview on the screen.

Try it Out. It should Work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but then I'll have the same exact problem on the new view. The issue is not with my views, is inside the UIWebView. Check the screenshot, that native player is generated when the UIWebView detects a YouTube video, I didn't create it.