# Making the background of my UIWebView transparent failed

Tags: ios, uiwebview, transparency

I am trying to make the background of my UIWebView transparent. I tried the things mentioned here:
[How to make a transparent UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646930/how-to-make-a-transparent-uiwebview)

well it works but only after I press a button on my webview, and is not transparent when it loads. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem was that I had put these messages in the function for the button.

```
  [self.webView setOpaque:NO];
  [self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

I put the in the viewDidLoad method and it worked.