# iOS Transparent background for WKWebView

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c, wkwebview

I'm in the process of migrating some code over from UIWebView to a WKWebView on a iOS project.
I'm currently trying to make a wkwebview transparent but the functionality doesn't seem work.
I could do this on a UIWebView by doing this

```
self.opaque = NO;  
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and setting the html page to be transparent via styling would allow me to see the view content underneath.

If I try the same code on a WKWebView the background of the html page isn't becoming transparent.
I've had search on google and there seems to be work around for MacOS X but I can't see to find a solution for iOS.

This is how it's done on a UIWebView ([How to make a transparent UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646930/how-to-make-a-transparent-uiwebview))
Has anyone any ideas if this is possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Try setting the alpha to 0. That will reduce the opacity.

Comment: changing the alpha on the view will impact all the components on the wkWebview. I'm only interested in making the background transparent.

Answer (score 8):

You can try out the following snippet:

```
webView.opaque = false
webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: are you sure the html loaded has a _transparent_ background?

Comment: But not a WKWebView , looks like I'll have to revert back to using a UIWebView for the moment.

Comment: Worked for me on a WKWebView

Comment: ```[webView setOpaque:NO];
     webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];``` for using Objective-C code.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly how our app works - we rely on the transparency. Our WkWebView is made transparent with this code:

```
_primaryWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame configuration:theConfiguration];
_primaryWebView.opaque = false;
_primaryWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Our web content hosted in the WkWebView has a transparent background, then for the areas of the page where we want to see the native content we place DIV elements sized properly, with a transparent background. This allows us to easily combine HTML and native iOS content.

Comment: Hello Chris , could you provide an example as I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Hello Chris , could you provide an example of your DIV elements sized properly as I still can't get it to work. In my html code I'm setting the background color using <style> body { background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3) } and I'm creating the wkWebView in exactly the same way but it's still not transparent. The same html page and settings work on UIWebView.

Comment: Thank you I've started a new project and the wkwebview is now transparent. It must have been a setting in my storyboard